# Center float boxes horizontally

Tags: css, html, css-float, alignment

I want to display some floating boxes (divs containing thumbnails) and the number of thumbnails depends on the current page width. For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1" style="float:left;width:120px;height:120px;margin-right:10px;">Thumbnail image here</div>
  <div class="box2" style="float:left;width:120px;height:120px;margin-right:10px;">Thumbnail image here</div>
  <div class="box3" style="float:left;width:120px;height:120px;margin-right:10px;">Thumbnail image here</div>
  <div class="box4" style="float:left;width:120px;height:120px;margin-right:10px;">Thumbnail image here</div>
    .......... ETC
</div>
```

the problem is that for a given width it shows for example 4 boxes on each row, but they are all left aligned and there is some white space to the right, how can i center horizontally for each row??

Something like this: http://realworldstyle.com/thumbs_3.html but with boxes centered horizontally on the page...

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but will not be able to do what you are wanting with straight CSS + HTML. (Take a look at @Pekka for an alternative, though if the row of thumbnails don't fill the whole row, they would be centered by themselves on the last row)

You would need to have a fixed width on the parent object `.container` with `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right:auto` which you cannot do since it is a fluid width page.

Here is how I would go about doing it, though it is sure to have some bugs you will need to work around:

1. Bind a javascript event to the `window.resize` event
2. Get the new document width and see how many thumbnails would fit on one row
3. Set the width of the `div.container` to be that width plus the little bit of margin on the right. This `div` would always have a `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `auto`

This will center the thumbnails as best as possible. Depending on your visual display, you may need an additional wrapping div to provide the `100% width` background.

Comment: Ok, think that this could be the simplest solution, i though that i could solve this only using CSS but it seems that i'll need to use javascript also...

Comment: Can the downvoter take the time to provide helpful feedback so I can make my answer better?

Comment: Fantastic! I've solved it with some help from jQuery and now it works... Many thanks dcneiner!!

Comment: No downvote from me, but just the same I would suggest css for the browsers that support it and use the javascript to just wrap the container in a table for IE. That way you don't have to bother with the resize stuff.

Comment: @jeroen My only problem with the other solutions, is they would break the grid pattern. By centering everything `text-align: center` the final row would not line up in a grid with the previous rows. Since the OP mentioned "thumbnails" I assumed it was something to which a consistent grid pattern is important.

Comment: @dcneiner: That´s true if you apply the inline-block stuff to the boxes, not if you apply it to .container.

Comment: @Pekka @jeroen thanks for the support guys. I am happy to learn if people take the time to say why they downvoted. Oh well.

Comment: The question is, why does this site allow downvoting without an explanation? And do the designers of this site care about their users?

Comment: @codyc4321 Yes, they care about their users. As for why downvotes without comments are allowed, please search for that topic on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 7):

I think the only way to get the elements centered is to work not with float, but setting the images `display: inline`. That way, you can align them at will using the parent container's `text-align` property.

But that will give you additional issues with vertical margins and setting height. But as far as I know, it's the only reliable cross-browser way as long as `inline-block` is not widely supported.

Comment: I think the question makes clear why your fix would not work.

Comment: @Pekka, SO doesn't like me :) It won't let me take back my down vote. Is it possible you can perform one more edit ?

Comment: +1 For great answer, didn't think about that. The last row of thumbs would not stay in a grid pattern.. I wonder if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Use an unordered list with inline list elements:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

That'll do as long as you don't have block-level elements inside the LI elements. Works also if you have more than one row of images ;) You can also use div's but using a list is semantically much more nicer.

Comment: This doesn't work, because you are using a fixed with (960px) in your example....

Comment: @fidoboy The width isn't needed for his example to work, but if there were 6 items per row, and 3 on the last. The last 3 would be centered and not in line with the previous rows.

Answer (score 1):

inline-block and auto margins on .container should do the trick for most browsers with perhaps text-align:center on body as well.

And if IE6 and IE7 don't play nice, you can always use javascript / jquery to wrap the whole thing in a table just for them.

Mind you, I wouldn't dare suggest a table solution for normal browsers, although it obviously works flawlessly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Style margin: 0 auto; will center the element. But you need to specify the width of the parent container.

```
<div style="width:100%; float:left; margin: 0 auto;">
   /* Your Child Elements */
</div>
```